# Case de switch duplicados en java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con los `case` del `switch`: una vez reciben el parámetro, eclipse me dice que los case están duplicados. Pego el código; agradecería alguna sugerencia para poder agrupar el número que da el *ramdom*, agruparlos en los `case`:

```
do { num = (int)Math.random()*20+1;
    
     switch (num) {
    
     case 0-5:
         edades.add(num);
         grup1++;
         break;
         
     case 6-10:
         edades.add(num);
         grup2++;
         break;
         
     case 10-15:
         edades.add(num);
         grup3++;
         break;
         
     case 16-19:
         edades.add(num);
         grup4++;
         break;
         }// fin del switch
}while(num!=20);//fin del bucle do
```

Comment: Para este tipo de casos te recomiendo mejor usar las condicionales if

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No conozco en profundidad las últimas versiones de Java - léase 11, 12, ... - pero por lo que he podido investigar no han introducido los switch con rangos como el que estás intentando emplear.

```
switch (num) {

 case 0-5:
     edades.add(num);
     grup1++;
     break;
     
 case 6-10:
     edades.add(num);
     grup2++;
     break;
     
 case 10-15:
     edades.add(num);
     grup3++;
     break;
     
 case 16-19:
     edades.add(num);
     grup4++;
     break;
 }// fin del switch
```

Lo que está pasando es que el compilador te evalúa los supuestos rangos como el resultado de la resta de enteros que estás poniendo, es decir

```
switch (num) {

 case -5:
     edades.add(num);
     grup1++;
     break;
     
 case -4:
     edades.add(num);
     grup2++;
     break;
     
 case -5:
     edades.add(num);
     grup3++;
     break;
     
 case -3:
     edades.add(num);
     grup4++;
     break;
 }// fin del switch
```

Con lo cual tienes un case repetido, el asociado a -5.

Puedes echarle un ojo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case) de StackOverflow con varias posibles soluciones. La más sencilla aunque quizás algo tediosa y repetitiva sería

```
switch(num) {
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
        edades.add(num);
        grup1++;
        break;
    case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10:
        edades.add(num);
        grup2++;
        break;
    case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
        edades.add(num);
        grup3++;
        break;
    case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19:
        edades.add(num);
        grup4++;
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
```

Por lo que apuntan en los comentarios de dicha pregunta, se espera que en un futuro
si permita ese tipo de construcciones, puede que esta respuesta quede obsoleta. Pero para eso todavía falta. ;-P

Por cierto, ojo que el 10 aparece en dos de tus rangos, el segundo y el tercero.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando de forma incorrecta el `case` para tomar rangos.

En java menores o iguales a 11 la forma correcta de usar el `switch` es de la siguiente forma:

```
switch (num) {

   case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
       edades.add(num);
       grup1++;
       break;
 }
```

A partir de java 12 en adelante hay un gran cambio en cuanto el uso de `switch` aunque también se puede seguir usando como versiones anteriores.

```
switch (num) {
    case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -> edades.add(num);
                             grup1++;    
}
```

Como puedes observar a partir de java 12 si queremos usar un rango de `case` podemos separar cada caso por una coma, otro cambio es que ya no es necesario el uso del `break`.

Tambien puedes cambiar `switch` por la condicional `if`

```
if(0<=num<=5)grup1++; 
else if (6<=num<=10) grup2++;
else if (11<=num<=15) grup3++;
else if (16<=num<=19) grup4++;
edades.add(num);//fuera de las condicionales porque en cualquier caso se agrega num a edades
```